# how to create foreignkey constraints in this scenario

Tags: mysql

How to create foreignkey constraints in this scenario?

One asterisk- primary key
Two asterisks- foreign key

Tutor table:

| **tutorId | firstname | surname | telephoneNo | qualification | employmentDate | introducedBy* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Course table:

| **courseCode | courseName | lengthHours | tuitonFee | tutorId* | roomNo* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: I would advice you to use the naming standard of id inside tutor, and tutor_id inside cource. Not tutorId on both that is. 
Some also likes prefixing with PK, SK and K.

Comment: Clearly you need tables for roomno and introducedby FKs but I'm not clear what scenario you are considering.

Comment: I've created a working fiddle for this. But as @P.Salmon is mentioning, you've not stated where these keys belong to. As such, in my fiddle, I've commented out their row so you will have to fill that in by yourself with the correct table name and column.

Comment: 'asterix- foreign key' . I have just reread this and you say foreign key in the singular are you hoping to create one foreign key over all the asterixed columns? if so that;s not possible and you should explain your intent to clarify..

Answer (score 0):

This is well documented here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp
I would recommend renaming your columns. Camelcase is one thing, but it is better to either use PascalCase or underscore  as separator. Do note that *firstname* is two words, which should follow your standard. You've also not stated what the reference table is for *roomNo* or *introducedBy*, so you will have to edit my code with that information. If they are indeed supposed to be keys, they should probably have ID in the column name.

Fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6EKuZ7DcCRsAvmrLGYcJrx/1

```
CREATE TABLE tutor (
    tutorId INT NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(50),
    surname varchar(50),
    telephoneNo varchar(50),
    qualification varchar(50),
    employmentDate datetime,
    introducedBy int,
    PRIMARY KEY (tutorId)
/*  FOREIGN KEY (introducedBy) REFERENCES ????? */
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE courseCode (
    courceCode int,
    courceName varchar(50),
    tutorId INT,
    lenghtHours INT,
    tuitonFee INT,
    roomNo varchar(50),
    INDEX par_ind (tutorId),
    PRIMARY KEY (courceCode),
/*  FOREIGN KEY (roomNo) REFERENCES ????? */
    FOREIGN KEY (tutorId) REFERENCES tutor(tutorId)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: 'asterix- foreign key' . I have just reread this and noted foreign key is singular perhaps op wants one foreign key over all the asterixed columns

Comment: Well, as much as I'd love to follow you up on that @P.Salmon - it simply does not make sense. Asterix is misspelled, so I would be careful to follow this to the letter. However, he has presented two tables, with a matching column ID. The other keys are not named ID for some reason. We can only assume what OP is doing right now, and I would personally assume that my answer here is correct. (Unless roomNo and courceCode is no keys at all, and should be varchar since they're not named ID anywhere).

With no more info, we can't know for sure what OP means. But I am hoping this is it.

Comment: Either way, these column names needs their naming standard revisited.